# Sticky position element don't stick to parent

Tags: html, css, sticky

So here's My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-8"></div>

    {{!-- Sticky Menu --}}
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div id="sidebar" class="container sidebar">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

And it's not working. What seems to be the problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please create [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can help you out quickly and also explain `what is not working`

Comment: @Sunil it should stick on scroll, but it's fixed and not scrolling.

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://www.bootply.com/QeqNJwctZY you must have some other styles interfering